# SQL query joining different tables and count

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am weak with SQL query syntax and i need to make one query with php symfony2.
I have table Company. It have column "city".
I have table CompanyCategory. It have columns "company_id" and "category_id".
I have table Category. It have column "name".

I need to get Total number of categories in all available cities.

Example:

```
["Riga" => 156,
"Berlin" => 225]
```

I have looked around for couple of hours but other examples didn't help me enough, because i can't understand such complex queries yet.

I've tried many cases before and now and every time getting different exceptions.

```
public function getCategoriesInCities() {
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT c.city, count(*) as categorycount FROM AdminBundle:Company c INNER JOIN AdminBundle:CompanyCategory s')
        ->getArrayResult();
}


[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got end of string.
```

Other case:

```
public function getCategoriesInCities() {
    return $asData = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT c.city, count(*) as categorycount FROM AdminBundle:Company c INNER JOIN AdminBundle:CompanyCategory s ON(c.id = s.company_id) GROUP BY c.city')
        ->getArrayResult();
}


[Syntax Error] line 0, col 123: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'ON'
```

Other case:

```
public function getCategoriesInCities() {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c.city, COUNT(*) as categorycount')
        ->innerJoin('AdminBundle:CompanyCategory ON(c.id = cc.company_id)', 'cc')
        ->groupBy('c.city')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
}

[Syntax Error] line 0, col 138: Error: Expected Literal, got 'BY'
```

etc.. can't find out how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple JOIN query..

```
SELECT t.city,count(*) as categoryCount
FROM Company t
INNER JOIN CompanyCategory s ON(t.id = s.company_ID)
GROUP BY t.city
```

You are not new to this site, so in the future, at least try to show some attempts and efforts that you did on your own.